# Is there any way to enable the Azure's management-api built-in rest API programmatically?

Tags: azure

My question relates to Azure API-Management-service and ARM templates. I have to be precise because of the redundant terms with different meanings. So forgive my unusual explanation.

Azure has a management-api resource that behaves like an api-gateway. Let's call it **gateway-x**. This resource has a feature called "Management REST API". You can enable this feature in the azure portal. Activating this feature provides a REST API that can interact with **gateway-x**

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest

**gateway-x** was created through ARM templates. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no property for activate the "Management REST API" as I could do in the web-portal. Is that correct? I was also looking for a workaround using the azure-cli to do that. "az apim" but nope, it can basically nothing.

I need that rest API available within my CI/CD pipeline. Doing this manually is not an option.

Any Ideas?

Comment: It should be this rest Api

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/tenantaccess/update#response

Comment: You can find the equivalent powershell command easily after you double check. No Azure cli for api management since it is still in preview